# What is the best way to use for large numbers in phpmyadmin, as the number I need it not show in the correct way

Tags: sql

I am trying to use phpmyadmin to add numbers to sql
my column is at the moment double, but it does not give me the correct info.  Did try decimal and binary also.

The number that I want to use is about 30 in length, it must be something like this 123,456,789,112,345,678,121.12345678.   The numbers can also be very smal (1.01)
If above cannot work, then is this possible 123456789112345678121.12345678

Just want to know if it is possible to do this in sql using phpmyadmin

Comment: Well, with comma's, that would have to be stored as a string because comma's are not numeric. Without the comma's, yes, that is possible too.

Comment: @Paul T. how is the second one posible

Comment: See [this example](https://imgbox.com/ZuWoGOWk) with PMA screenshots.